# Different layout results on same device model

Tags: css, ionic-framework

Developing an app using ionic 5 and getting different layout results on same device model. Tested on different devices - Samsung XCover 4s. Why it differs even if phone models are the same and both uses Android 10?

[image]

[image]

Comment: check both devices have updates `Webview`